# How to log all rest api calls in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, web-services, magento-enterprise-2

Is there any way to log all the requested rest API with details (requested URL, methods, parameters, time, etc.,) in Magento2?

earlier I have logged all the rest of the API which was related to products using the model (V1.php) in Magento 1. but in magento2 all the methods called in the same location for both API and backend usage to create/update/get.

here how can I know if the request from API?

Please suggest any solution to log APIs.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This may not be a good way to log the Rest API]

We should try with Plugin - `Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest::dispatch()`:

app/code/Vendor/WebApiLog/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest">
        <plugin name="rest-api-log"
                type="Vendor\WebApiLog\Model\Plugin\RestApiLog"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/WebApiLog/Model/Plugin/RestApiLog.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\WebApiLog\Model\Plugin;

class RestApiLog
{
    public function beforeDispatch(
        \Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    )
    {
        $request->getModuleName();
        $request->getActionName();
        $request->getPathInfo();

    }
}
```

Comment: how to get the params in this dispatch method, i tried  `$request->getParams(); ` it returns the empty array. even `$request->getModuleName(); $request->getActionName(); `these two methods also returns null value.

Comment: @Sathish all of the methods above returns null value?

Comment: not all some of the methods. i used `$request->getContent()` to collect the inputs. thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following FOSS module:

https://github.com/vladflonta/magento2-webapi-log

Comment: Does not seem to work on Magento 2.4 at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, under MIT license:

https://github.com/ghostunicorns/module-webapi-logs

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just needed something like that for Magento 2.4 :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can also check this light weight API logging module
https://github.com/mosesdinakaran/magento-log

[image]

It has the below features

- Able to log all the API logs
- Able to log logged in users API calls
- Able to log guest user API calls
- Able to log only a specific api calls such as custom api call, cart, CMS, Product, Order etc
- Able to log a specific user api calls.
- The API logs contain both the request and Response
- The logs are made in a separate file
- This extension doesn't override any CORE Api class.